# Javascript does not redirect and time is stay same in Django Application. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

Hi everyone I try to build web application with using django and js. It is kind of chat application there are rooms and each room have time after time is up. I want to delete room. While I making test, I realize if one user in room,other user in list page, room does not delete when 1 user in room and other list page. Time is stay 1 seconds How can ı solve this problem. Can you help me? Thank You.

room_detail_page

```
  function updateRemainingTime() {
        // Sunucuya AJAX isteği gönder
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/remaining-time/' + roomName + '/', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var remainingTime = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                // Kalan süreyi güncelle
                document.getElementById('remaining-time').textContent = remainingTime.minutes + ':' + remainingTime.seconds;
                if (remainingTime.minutes <= 0 && remainingTime.seconds <= 0) {
                    deleteRoom(roomName);
                
            }
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    function deleteRoom(roomId) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/delete-room/' + roomId + '/', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            window.location.href = '/home';
            location.reload()
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
setInterval(updateRemainingTime, 1000);
```

room_list_page

```
function updateRemainingTime(roomId) {
        // Sunucuya AJAX isteği gönder
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/remaining-time/' + roomId + '/', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var remainingTime = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                // Kalan süreyi güncelle
                var remainingTimeElement = document.getElementById('remaining-time-' + roomId);
            
                remainingTimeElement.textContent = remainingTime.minutes + ':' + remainingTime.seconds;
                if (remainingTime.minutes <= 0 && remainingTime.seconds <= 0 ) {
                    // If remaining time is 0 or negative, delete the room
                    deleteRoom(roomId);
                    
                }
                
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    // Belirli aralıklarla her oda için zamanı güncelle
    function deleteRoom(roomId) {
        // Sunucuya AJAX isteği gönder
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/delete-room/' + roomId + '/', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}');  // Add CSRF token if needed
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
               location.reload()
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    room_ids.forEach(function(roomId) {
        setInterval(function() { updateRemainingTime(roomId); }, 1000); // Her saniyede bir güncelle
    });
```

api.py

```
def remaining_time_api(request, room_id):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=room_id)
    remaining_time = room.remaining_time()
    seconds = remaining_time.seconds % 60
    minutes = (remaining_time.seconds // 60) % 60
    return JsonResponse({'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds})

def delete_room(request, room_id):
    room = get_object_or_404(Room, id=room_id)
    room.delete()
    return redirect('/home')
```

Comment: I didn't try your code out but you're creating a race condition between multiple clients. If you're designing the timing to be handled client side with a polling strategy this won't work. One or the other client is going to end up deleting the `Room` object first causing the other one to get an error. You can try handling that but you probably want something like a websocket instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah I have problem with it but ı have to use timing is there any suggestions.